# Azure Powershell - Can't find classic VMs

Tags: powershell, azure

I'm trying to retrieve a complete list of VMs through PowerShell, but I'm having trouble pulling Classic VMs, and I'm having trouble understanding the distinction between RM and regular cmdlets, particularly when it comes to subscriptions.

`Get-AzureRMSubscription` correctly returns a complete list of the subscriptions my Azure account has access to. `Get-AzureSubscription` returns nothing. This means that I can correctly pull all of the new style VMs from any one subscription using `Get-AzureRMVM`, but since I can't find a 'classic' style subscription, I can't pull any of my existing classic VMs as I can't define which subscription to look in.

I can successfully view all VMs in all Subscriptions through the portal, but not through Powershell for whatever reason. I'm all out of ideas, is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/744858/whats-the-difference-between-get-azurermvm-and-get-azurevm

Answer (score 4):

`Get-AzureRMSubscription` `Get-AzureSubscription` `Get-AzureRMVM` are resource mode cmdlet, your VMs are classic mode VM, you should use classic cmdlets. Just use the following cmdlets.

```
#login your classic account
Add-AzureAccount
# Enumerates all configured subscriptions on your local machine.
Get-AzureSubscription  
# Select the subscription to use
Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "mysubscription" 
#get classic VM
Get-AzureVM
```

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, `Get-AzureSubscription` returns nothing, and therefore `Select-AzureSubscription` fails because it can't find a subscription to assign, and thus `Get-AzureVM` fails because a subscription hasn't been assigned.

Comment: @CNoyer Do you use the same account on Portal and PowerShell? Could you provide some screenshots about your VM on Portal? Also, you could check your PowerShell version. `Get-Module -ListAvailable -Name Azure -Refresh` The latest version is 3.7.0

Comment: It may be because when you use add-AzureAccount , you are logging into your personal Microsoft account and your subscription is on your work account or vice Versa. When you login to Microsoft using Add-AzureAccount, you get two options work or personal. Make sure you choose the one
Under which the subscription is active.

Comment: Both New and Classic VMs are fully viewable through the GUI Portal, both using the same account. I made sure my Powershell Azure version was the latest, so that can't be the problem.

Comment: @CNoyer What Azure region you use? AzureCloud for global Azure ,AzureChinaCloud for Azure operated by 21Vianet in China or Azure for Germany? If you don't use global Azure, when you login you should use `Add-AzureAccount -Environment  AzureGermanCloud`. This cmdlet is login Azure for Germany.

Comment: We're based in NZ so it's likely we're using the Global one.

Comment: Could you try other PC, what is your client OS, Windows 10 or others?

Answer (score 1):

Classic VM's were the norm when Azure was used using manage.windowsazure.com where, each virtual machine had a cloud service attached to it by default and resources such as Virtual Networks and Firewalls (ACL) were static to each resource.

Azure Resource Manager (ARM) based deployments gives you the power of having flexible deployment models (e.g. one firewall/NSG for x number of VM's). A detailed study can be found on the below link:

[Azure Resource Manager based deployments explained](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-overview)

For your question you can use the below Cmdlets to get all classic virtual machines.

```
#login your classic (work AD / Personal) account using the pop-up
Add-AzureAccount
# Get All subscriptions under the non-rm account. DO NOT USE Get-AzureRMSubscription for any classic resources

Get-AzureSubscription  
# Select the subscription to use using the Subscription name or ID (if all your subscription names say pay-as-you-go for e.g. you may want to use your subscription ID)

Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName "enter-your-subscription-name" OR -SubscriptionId "alternatively-use-subscription-id"

#List all the VM's in a variable for further use (if needed, else direct display)

$vmList = Get-AzureVM

#Output the Virtual Machines on the subscription

Write-Output ($vmList)
```

Done !

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, `Get-AzureSubscription` returns nothing, and therefore `Select-AzureSubscription` fails because it can't find a subscription to assign, and thus `Get-AzureVM` fails because a subscription hasn't been assigned.

Comment: It may be because when you use add-AzureAccount , you are logging into your personal Microsoft account and your subscription is on your work account or vice Versa. When you login to Microsoft using Add-AzureAccount, you get two options work or personal. Make sure you choose the one
Under which the subscription is active.

Comment: An account was created specifically for this functionality - a generic VM admin account - so this can't possibly be the case.